# Does every group have a representation?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

For any set $A$, we can give it an group structure and make it a free group. For example:
$$\mathbb Z=<a;aa^{-1}=1>$$

Further more, we can introduce some relation on it:
$$\mathbb Z_2=<a;a^2=1>$$
 $$\mathbb Z_2\times{\mathbb Z_3}=<a,b;a^2=b^3=1,ab=ba>$$

So if a group can be represented by the form:
$$<a_1,a_2...;r_1,r_2...>$$

then we call that it has a representation.

> **Question:** Does every group have a representation?

Below is my attempt:

> Let $G$ be a group. If we remove the group structure of $G$, then we can give it a trivial free relation: $G^{*}=<g;gg^{-1}=1>$.
>    Then we consider the map
>    $$\sigma:G^{*}\rightarrow{G}$$
>    $$g_1^{\varepsilon_1}...g_n^{\varepsilon_n}\mapsto{g_1^{\varepsilon_1}...g_n^{\varepsilon_n}}$$

So now I'm confused. Is the map well-defined? And what should I do next step?

Comment: The standard English word is "presentation" not "representation". Presentations are (surjective) homomorphisms from well understood objects, representations are homomorphisms to well understood objects.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649661. It's the same solution as Berci's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, let $X:=\{x_g\}_{g\in G}$ be the set of variables and take relations
$x_gx_h=x_u$ whenever $gh=u$.

If you wish to generate it *as semigroup* you indeed need the extra *symbols* $x_g^{-1}$ and relations $x_gx_g^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Is $X/\sim$ isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: Of course. We have a surjection $F(X)\to G$ and the kernel contains exactly those $x_{g_1}^{\epsilon_1}\dots x_{g_n}^{\epsilon_n}$ words which give $g_1^{\epsilon_1}\dots g_n^{\epsilon_n}=1$. But these already follow by the given relations.